# Сложности в использовании @media

Tags: html

Сделал страницу, которая идеально помещается в разрешение 1280x894
Требуется, чтобы она целиком отображалась на всех устройствах - от меню до футера
Для этого я попробовал на более маленьких разрешениях сдвигать вверх футер и чёрный блок под ним, закрывающий остальной контент

Проверял работу сайта на разных разрешениях на http://quirktools.com/screenfly

@media почему-то не работает, и указанные в нём настройки не включаются при проверке на подходящих устройствах

Привожу использованный код:

```css
@media screen and (min-device-height: 849px) and (max-device-height: 899px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 51px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 51px
    }
}
 
@media screen and (min-device-height: 799px) and (max-device-height: 848px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 101px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 101px
    }
}
 
@media screen and (min-device-height: 767px) and (max-device-height: 799px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 133px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 133px
    }
}
 
@media screen and (min-device-height: 600px) and (max-device-height: 766px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 300px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 300px
    }
```

Сайт, над которым ведётся работа: lvtgroup.ru

Я новичок, поэтому буду очень благодарен, если поможете разобраться и решить проблему

Comment: `device-height` вместо `min-device-height` попробуйте использовать, возможно не поддерживается полноценно этот вариант написания. Вроде бы, только Хромом. Ну и с `min-device-width` аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

```js
@media screen and (max-device-height: 899px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 51px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 51px
    }
}
 
@media screen and (max-device-height: 848px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 101px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 101px
    }
}
 
@media screen and (max-device-height: 799px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 133px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 133px
    }
}
 
@media screen (max-device-height: 766px) {
    body footer #relativefooter {
        bottom: 300px
    }
    
    body footer .end {
        bottom: 300px
    }
```

Попробуй написать условия вот так. Так проще и должно заработать.